# spring mvc dao and service bean mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, javabeans

I am new to Spring and hibernate. 
I am trying to learn the best practices and design methodoligies in j2ee apps.

I have a managed to create a basic spring mvc web app. now lookin for that 
- how should i map my service beans to dao beans or should just use dao beans only. 
- Is there any need to make DAO classes singleton
- If i use same dao bean for the jsp, then e.g. onSubmit if I have to enter data on multiple tables (dao beans) then how would I do that. 
1 service bean to more than 1 dao beans??

and any refrence material on designing good web app using spring hibernate would appreciated ;)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must use service bean. service logic should be there only.
DAO should only for DB related operation.

Now you can inject multiple DAO in your service bean.

Comment: can i inject DAO into service while only using spring-mvc and would  only need to add applicationContext.xml??

Comment: @user330281 yes you should inject DAO into service layers, and about `while only using spring-mvc and would only need to add applicationContext.xml??` this part is not clear to me

Answer (score 2):

FWIW - I just went through a similar learning process on Spring.  The good news is, there are a lot of examples out on google; the bad news is, there are not a lot of "complete" examples that are good for rookies (also if you are going to target v3 Spring, there is a lot of pre-v3 stuff out there that can be confusing based on the new baseline).  What worked for me was the following: started with the sample applications on the SpringSource site (http://www.springsource.org/documentation).  Between their handful of examples, there are just about all the pieces you will need, at least in minimal form.  When I found something in those examples that I needed, I googled based on similar terms (some of the @ annotations etc) to find more complete information/better examples on that given topic.  Many of those searches led me back to this site, which is why I started frequenting here - lots of good questions already answered.  I guess this isn't an overly insightful answer, but this process got me up and working through the basics in a fairly quick amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

DAO layer and service layer are different entities:

DAO is responsible for getting and putting single objects from\to DB. For example, get User(id, name, lastname) from DB.

Service layer is responsible for your business logic. It can use several DAO objects for making one action. For example, send message from one user to another and save it in sent folder of first user and in inbox of recipient.

Answer (score 1):

A service is about presenting a facade to the user that exposes business functions that the user can take. Basically, if you have a set of low-level use cases, the methods on the service would line up with individual user actions. Services are transactional, generally if the user does something we want all the consequences of that action to be committed together. The separation between controller and service means we have one place to put webapp-specific functionality, like getting request parameters, doing validation, and choosing where to forward or redirect to, and a separate place to put the business logic, stuff that doesn't depend on webapp apis and is about what objects get updated with what values and get persisted using which data access objects.

I see a lot of cases where people seem to think they need one service for each dao. I think their assumption is that because Data Access Objects and Controllers and Models are fairly mechanical about how they're defined, services must be the same way, and they construct them with no regard for the use cases that are being implemented. What happens is, in addition to having a lot of useless service boilerplate code, all the business logic ends up in the controller jumbled up with the web-specific code, and the controllers become big and unmanageable. If your application is very simple you can get by with this for a while, but it is disorganized, it's hard to test, and it's generally a bad idea. Separation of concerns, keeping infrastructure code in one place and business code in another, is what we should be aiming for, and using services properly is very helpful in getting there.